# CAS 5.1.0-RC1 not reading service config from services directory(?)

Tags: configuration, saml-2.0, cas

I'm trying to get the CAS 5.x.x SAML2 IdP working with an external Tomcat 8. I've tried CAS 5.0.2 and newly released CAS 5.0.3 and got the SAML 2 SSO protocol going. Unfortunately the final POST (redirect) back to the service from CAS was missing the RelayState, which is a known bug to be targeted for 5.1.0. So I tried the new CAS 5.1.0-RC1 with the same configuration. But I got the following error:

2017-02-21 11:06:40,741 WARN [org.apereo.cas.support.saml.web.idp.profile.SSOPostProfileHandlerController] - <[https://ts3.security.army.mil/TS3AuthFilter] is not found in the registry or service access is denied. Ensure service is registered in service registry>

I do have a JSON SAML service config in WEB-INF/classes/services, which was working with CAS 5.0.x. Comparing the Tomcat console logs, I found that CAS 5.1.0-RC1 log was missing JsaonServiceRegistryDao's logging to load the services configs in WEB-INF/classes/services/. My questions are:

- Does CAS 5.1.0-RC1 still deploy a JsonServiceRegistryDao to read in the initial services config from WEB-INF/classes?
- If so then why the same SAML service config did not work?
- If not, then how can I register the SAML service now w/o using the Service Management?

Thanks,

Gang

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the following property: ***cas.serviceRegistry.initFromJson***?
Default is false, we had to set it to true...

Cheers,
Chris